# meta redirect with php inside

Tags: php, meta

I have a php file. In it I want an error redirect like this:

```
<?php

$ponka = somerandomsite.com;

if (1=1)
    {echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=http://$ponka/error.php">'}
?>
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: I see many syntax errors here.

Comment: my bad, I just typed the problem I am having, I have the correct code at the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `php` contains lots of errors, here's a working sample

```
<?php
$site = $_GET['site'] // will get the variable $site form a url like script.php?site=somerandomsite.com
$ponka = "somerandomsite.com";

if ($site == $ponka){
    echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' Content='0; URL=http://$ponka/error.php'>";
}
?>
```

Also, remeber that `php` as a function called [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
<?php
$site = $_GET['site'] // will get the variable $site form a url like script.php?site=somerandomsite.com
$ponka = "somerandomsite.com";
if ($site == $ponka){
   header("Location: http://$ponka/error.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: tried your method 1st method (which is almost similar to mine), it redirected me to this: http://%24ponka/error.php

Comment: My bad... I used single quotes and the variable doesn't expand. 1 m going to update the first answer.

Comment: $ponka = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];